# cannot find symbol Error in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have 3 class file, when i compile the class which extends the other class gives compilation error like symbol not found.

```
public class  Animal {  
    public static void hide() {  
        System.out.println("Hide Method Of Animal");  
    }  

    public void override() {  
        System.out.println("The Override method of Animal");  
    }  
}
```

```
public class Cat extends Animal {  
    public static void hide() {  
        System.out.println("Hide Method Of Cat");  
    }  

    public void override() {  
        System.out.println("The Override method of Animal");  
    }  
}
```

```
public class TestAnimal {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        Cat myCat = new Cat();  
        Animal myAnimal =  (Animal)myCat;  
        myAnimal.hide();  
        myAnimal.override();  
    }  
}
```

I get this error:

```
TestAnimal.java:6: cannot find symbol  
symbol  : class Cat  
location: class com.Test.TestAnimal  
            Cat myCat = new Cat();  
            ^
```

Any help on this???

Comment: do you have anything like: package com.Test; at the beginning of your class files?

Comment: Yes Even after adding package i get same error. And all these class are present in same path

Comment: You should publish show us your packages, directory structure and the way you invoke your `java` application.

Comment: D:\Mine\CoreJava\Programming\src

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see if there is a .class file for each .java file after you compile.  If not, make sure that each one has a .class file.

When you run, use the -classpath argument to point to the directory where all the .class files live.

You sound like you could use some instruction on compiling and running Java.

http://www.horstmann.com/bigj/help/compiler/tutorial.html

Here's the spoon feeding answer:

1. Go to your d:\Mine\CoreJava\Programming directory in a command
   shell.
2. Create a directory /classes
3. Compile by typing javac -d classes -cp classes src/*.java
4. You should see all the .class files created at once.
5. Run by typing java -cp .;classes FullClassNameOfYourMain

Comment: The Animal class compiles without any error, its only when i compile Cat class i get error

Comment: Right - Cat depends on Animal, but the compiler has no way to find it because you didn't tell it about the Animal.class file.  Use the -classpath argument when you compile, too.

Answer (score 4):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with your code. Here's what I've done. See if you did everything right:

```
$ cat > Animal.java
public class  Animal
{
    public static void hide()
    {
    System.out.println("Hide Method Of Animal");
    }

    public void override()
    {
    System.out.println("The Override method of Animal");
    }
}

$ cat > Cat.java
public class Cat extends Animal
{
    public static void hide()
    {
    System.out.println("Hide Method Of Cat");
    }

    public void override()
    {
    System.out.println("The Override method of Animal");
    }
}

$ cat > TestAnimal.java
public class TestAnimal
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Cat myCat = new Cat();
    Animal myAnimal =  (Animal)myCat;
    myAnimal.hide();
    myAnimal.override();
    }
}

$ javac TestAnimal.java

$ ls
Animal.class  Animal.java  Cat.class  Cat.java  TestAnimal.class  TestAnimal.java

$ java TestAnimal
Hide Method Of Animal
The Override method of Animal
```

I used copy-paste to get your code, as you can see. Notice that after compiling there are three `.class` files in addition to your `.java` files.